# Javascript to loop through asp checkboxes to see if any are checked

Tags: javascript, c#, checkbox, ascx

I am having an issue looping though asp checkboxes in an ascx file to see each individual element's "state" (checked or not). Here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvApplicationForms" OnItemCommand="lvAttachedDocuments_OnItemCommand"
    DataKeyNames="FormID" OnPreRender="lvApplicationForms_PreRender" OnItemDataBound="lvApplicationForms_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="<%# (Container.DisplayIndex + 1 )% 2 == 0 ? "EvenRow" : "OddRow" %>" data-formname='<%#Eval("FormName")%>'>
            <td class="fieldName_td" style="text-align: center">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsExposed" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" onclick="javascript:return CheckedChange(this)" OnChecked='<%# Eval("IsPublished") %>'
                    Enabled='<%# CanCounterSignAndExpose && Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CanBePublished")) %>' />
            </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Essentially my issue is that I have a save button on the page that I want enabled only if at least one element in the checkboxes is checked. If none are, keep the save button disabled. I know how to disable the save button, I just don't know how to loop though the checkboxes to get their "state".

Answer (score 0):

if you can add a reference to [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), then this can be done in one line using the [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

when you do a `$('#mySection input:checked')`, it returns you an array of checked checkboxes which you can further process as required.

Comment: Friend you can also do that with `document.querySelectorAll('#mySection input:checked');`, I mean, in case jQuery is not an option.
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: Indeed there is a glitch, some people get to make it work somehow but no one explains well. I think jQuery does resolve that internally, again I'm all for using jQuery, it rocks. But there are alternatives for those who prefer not to as well.

Comment: this link shows how it is done on jQuery if you want to get your hands dirty.. :) : http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/08-selector.html